# Can indirect object inside PDF be nested?

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to understand whether indirect objects (declared with the obj/endobj keywords) can reside inside e.g. array, dictionary entries or other indirect objects.
For example
`[ 3 0 0 obj (something) end ]` would parse an array of `[3, <indirect object>]` if this was allowed.

From what I can see all indirect objects are always at the top level in a PDF, and the fact that object streams exist suggests me that this can't be possible, but I can't find a definite answer in the ISO standard.

EDIT:
It turns out that the ISO standard was not that clear, but the latest spec from Adobe is a bit clearer:

> Note:  In the data structures that make up a PDF document, certain
>   values are required to be specified as indirect object references. Except where this is explicitly  called out, any object (other than a stream) may
>   be specified either directly or as an  indirect  object  reference; 
>   the  semantics  are  entirely  equivalent

Even if above it says

> Any object in a PDF file may be labeled as an  indirect object.

So I'm still not 100% sure.

Comment: Indirect objects cannot be contained in other objects, only referenced from them. At first glance there does not appear to be a single clear statement on that issue, though. The nearest thing is "Except were documented to the contrary any object value may be a direct or an indirect reference" which is inappropriately formulated, though: **a** after "a direct" the word "object" is missing, and **b** instead of "may" it should have been "must".

Comment: Very interesting question! It really seems to be an oversight in the specification that this is not explicitly stated.